# Skype duplicates an icon on the dock

Tags: updates, 20.04, icons, skype, dock

After updating from 18.04 to 20.04 Skype started to duplicate icon on the dock:

[image]

The first icon has been added as a favorite. So when I click it the second, below with poor quality, appears.
Expected behavior is an orange dot as for terminal on the dock.

Comment: Generally the reason for such a behavior is having more than one `.desktop` file that launches the application. You can search **for all `.desktop` files** on your system and find how many are related to the `skype` executable.

Comment: sudo find / -type f -name "*.desktop" | grep "skype" give me:
/snap/skype/153/meta/gui/skypeforlinux.desktop
/snap/skype/153/snap/gui/skypeforlinux.desktop
/snap/skype/153/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/skypeforlinux.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux.desktop

Comment: Looks like only the /snap/skype/153/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/skypeforlinux.desktop doesn't have StartupWMClass=Skype. But it is not possible  to edit it. So I've tried to save edited version into the ~/.local/share/application and restarted gnome. It didn't help.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, thanks! I had the same issue with Terminal and have found out that I had a "gnome-terminal.desktop" in the `~/.local/share/application` I had created before. Shame it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is caused by the way how `snap` installs Skype.
As a workaround I just installed `.deb` version from Skype website.